# "Contour not rendered for non-finite ZData"

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot a frequency characteristic equation using ezplot, but Matlab gives the following warning, "Contour not rendered for non-finite ZData". I have used this command to plot frequency equations previously but now I get a warning and the plot display is empty and it does not change the axis range as well. Can someone please help. Would be much appreciated.

Here's the code i'm using.

% Transfer Matrix for Case-I, thin rotor

```
clear all; 
clc;

EI = 1626;
l = 0.15;
m = 0.44108;
It = 2.178*10^-4;
I_p = 2.205*10^-5;
Itr = 0.24;
I_pr = 0.479;
syms p n;

F = [1 l*1i l^2/(2*EI)*1i l^3/(6*EI);
    0 1 l/EI -l^2/(2*EI)*1i;
    0 0 1 -l*1i;
    0 0 0 l];

P = [ 1 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0;
    0 -It*p^2+I_p*n*p 1 0;
    -m*p^2 0 0 1];

P_r = [1 0 0 0; 
      0 1 0 0; 
      0 -Itr*p^2+I_pr*n*p 1 0; 
      -m*p^2 0 0 1]; 

A = F*P*F*P*F*P*F;
B = P_r*F*P*F*P*F;

r = A(1,2)/A(1,4);
a12_p = 0;
a22_p = A(2,2)-r*A(2,4);
a32_p = A(3,2)-r*A(3,4);
a42_p = A(4,2)-r*A(4,4);

Ap(2,2) = a22_p;
Ap(3,2) = a32_p;
Ap(4,2) = a42_p;
Ap(4,4) = 1;

C = B*Ap;

M = [C(3,2) C(3,4);
    C(4,2) C(4,4)];

sol = det(M);
ezplot(sol,[-2*10^10 2*10^10]);
```

The sol is displayed if u ask for it but the plot doesn't display.
Thanks in advance for ur help !! Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, presumably you have something "non-finite" (e.g `NaN`, `Inf`, etc) in the variable you're trying to plot.  I suggest you examine `M` and `sol` and see if they look like you'd expect them to.

Comment: I c ur point nkjt. Well the M matrix is just the matrix i get from multiplying the previous matrices and its determinant is what is saved in 'sol' and that's what i want to plot. I looked at the elements of M and sol as well. Seem reasonable, except for that it has very high powers of 'p', but that was to be expected in this case.